# How python prioritizes instruction while parsing?

Tags: python

I'm studying over parsing with python. I have user-defined instructions. So I have to specify precedence of them. I find an example here is the [link](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/example.html)
I don't understand what they do in here

```
precedence = (
    ('left','PLUS','MINUS'),
    ('left','TIMES','DIVIDE'),
    ('right','UMINUS'),
)
```

how python prioritizes them?
and also those too

```
def p_statement_assign(t):
    'statement : NAME EQUALS expression'
    names[t[1]] = t[3]

def p_statement_expr(t):
    'statement : expression'
    print(t[1])
```

What does it mean to write 'statement : expression' in quotation marks? How python understand and make sense of them?

I'm adding my instruction too. I will use them for drawing something in my program

```
F n -> go on n step
R n -> turn right n degree
L n -> Repeat the parentheses n times 
COLOR f -> f: line color
PEN n -> line thickness
```

[image]

Comment: you have to establish your own hierarchy between the operations. Which one you choose?

Comment: _"What does it mean to write 'statement : expression' in quotation marks? How python understand and make sense of them?"_ if the first line of a function or class is a string, without assigning it to a variable, then it is treated as a "docstring" https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/ i.e. documentation for the function or class. The convention is usually to use triple-quotes though e.g. `"""statement : expression"""` so they stand out a bit from other code. As far as your program goes it is a no-op, but Python makes it available for introspection via the `__doc__` attribute of the func or class

Comment: @cards yes i know it. but i dont know how to write it as a code. i suppose code would be like in the link which I add. but I don't know how to code it.

Answer (score 1):

These instructions are read by ply and any Python function/class/module can have these strings write at the beginning of them called `docstring` and you can use `__doc__` attribute to retrieve them. Ply cleverly uses them as annotations to define the parsing rules. The rule can be interpreted as such: `statement: NAME EQUALS expression` means if there is a token stream that matches the sequence first with NAME, then EQUALS sign and finally an expression, it will be reduced to a statement.

The same is for precedence variable, which is also read by ply and ply uses this variable to define precedence rule.

I recommend you read the [ply documentation](https://ply.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ply.html) before using it as you need to know the basics about tokenizing and parsing before you can use a compiler construction tool like ply.